# element tree treats similar files differently

Tags: python, parsing, element

Here are two different files that my python (2.6) script encounters.  One will parse, the other will not.  I'm just curious as to why this happens.

This xml file will not parse and the script will fail:

```
<Landfire_Feedback_Point_xlsform id="fbfm40v10" instanceID="uuid:9e062da6-b97b-4d40-b354-6eadf18a98ab" submissionDate="2013-04-30T23:03:32.881Z" isComplete="true" markedAsCompleteDate="2013-04-30T23:03:32.881Z" xmlns="http://opendatakit.org/submissions">
<date_test>2013-04-17</date_test>
<plot_number>10</plot_number>
<select_multiple_names>BillyBob</select_multiple_names>
<geopoint_plot>43.2452830500 -118.2149402900 210.3000030518 3.0000000000</geopoint_plot><fbfm40_new>GS2</fbfm40_new>
<select_grazing>NONE</select_grazing>
<image_close>1366230030355.jpg</image_close>
<plot_note>No road present.</plot_note>
<n0:meta xmlns:n0="http://openrosa.org/xforms">
<n0:instanceID>uuid:9e062da6-b97b-4d40-b354-6eadf18a98ab</n0:instanceID>
</n0:meta>
</Landfire_Feedback_Point_xlsform>
```

This xml file will parse correctly and the script succeeds:

```
<Landfire_Feedback_Point_xlsform id="fbfm40v10">
<date_test>2013-05-14</date_test>
<plot_number>010</plot_number>
<select_multiple_names>BillyBob</select_multiple_names>
<geopoint_plot>43.26630563 -118.39881809 351.70001220703125 5.0</geopoint_plot>
<fbfm40_new>GR1</fbfm40_new>
<select_grazing>HIGH</select_grazing>
<image_close>fbfm40v10_PLOT_010_ID_6.jpg</image_close>
<plot_note>Heavy grazing</plot_note>
<meta><instanceID>uuid:90e7d603-86c0-46fc-808f-ea0baabdc082</instanceID></meta>
</Landfire_Feedback_Point_xlsform>
```

Here is a little python script that demonstrates that one will work, while the other will not.  I'm just looking for an explanation as to why one is seen by ElementTree as an xml file while the other isn't.  Specifically, the one that doesn't seem to parse fails with a "'NONE' type doesn't have a 'text' attribute" or something similar.  But, it's because it doesn't seem to consider the file as xml or it can't see any elements beyond the opening line.  Any explanation or direction with regard to this error would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Python script:

```
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree


def replace_xml_attribute_in_file(original_file,element_name,attribute_value):
    #THIS FUNCTION ONLY WORKS ON XML FILES WITH UNIQUE ELEMENT NAMES
    #  -DUPLICATE ELEMENT NAMES WILL ONLY GET THE FIRST ELEMENT WITH A GIVEN NAME

    #split original filename and add tempfile name
    tempfilename="temp.xml"
    rootsplit = original_file.rsplit('\\')  #split the root directory on the backslash
    rootjoin = '\\'.join(rootsplit[:-1]) #rejoin the root diretory parts with a backslash -minus the last 
    temp_file = os.path.join(rootjoin,tempfilename) 
    et = ElementTree.parse(original_file)
    author=et.find(element_name)
    author.text = attribute_value
    et.write(temp_file)
    if os.path.exists(temp_file) and os.path.exists(original_file): #if both the original and the temp files exist
        os.remove(original_file)                                    #erase the original
        os.rename(temp_file,original_file)                          #rename the new file
    else:
        print "Something went wrong."

replace_xml_attribute_in_file("testfile1.xml","image_close","whoopdeedoo.jpg");
```

Comment: What makes you think it's not treating the second one as XML, or stopping after the first line, or whatever? When I take your first example and `print et.getroot().getchildren()`, it gives me 9 child nodes, so clearly it _is_ treating it as XML, with more than just one line. So… what's your _actual_ problem? Is it acting differently for you? Or is, e.g., the `find` not finding anything, and you're just assuming that means it isn't parsing anything at all rather than checking?

Comment: Also, in the future, don't just try to vaguely describe your error; paste the actual error traceback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Here is a little python script that demonstrates that one will work, while the other will not. I'm just looking for an explanation as to why one is seen by ElementTree as an xml file while the other isn't.

Your code doesn't demonstrate that at all. It demonstrates that they're both seen by ElementTree as valid XML files chock full of nodes. They both parse just fine, they both read past the first line, etc.

The only problem is that the first one doesn't have a node named 'image_close', so your code doesn't work.

You can see that pretty easily:

```
for node in et.getroot().getchildren():
    print node.tag
```

You get 9 children of the root, with either version.

And the output to that should show you the problem. The node you want is actually named `{http://opendatakit.org/submissions}image_close` in the first example, rather than `image_close` as in the second.

And, as you can probably guess, this is because of the `namespace=http://opendatakit.org/submissions` in the root node. ElementTree uses the ["James Clark notation"](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xmlns.htm) for mapping unknown-namespaced names to universal names.

Anyway, because none of the nodes are named `image_close`, the `et.find(element_name)` returns `None`, so your code stores `author=None`, then tries to assign to `author.text`, and gets an error.

As for how to fix this problem… well, you could learn how namespaces work by default in ElementTree, or you could upgrade to Python 2.7 or install a newer ElementTree for 2.6 that lets you customize things more easily. But if you want to do custom namespace handling and also stick with your old version… I'd start with [this article](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2004/06/30/py-xml.html) (and its two predecessors) and [this one](http://www.xml.com/pub/a/2003/02/12/py-xml.html).

Comment: "You can see that pretty easily:"
"And, as you can probably guess,"
Crackin' me up with all that.  Anyhow, I really appreciate the help, although I don't understand XML all that well (just enough to be dangerous), and I certainly have no idea what a 'namespace' is or the difference between an element and a node.  But, after reading your response a few times, I think I can smell what you're getting at.  I really do appreciate the help and understanding.  I'll get to reading....and making things workable.  Thank you for the sanity.

Comment: The _right_ solution pretty much requires understanding XML namespaces, and how ET deals with them, which is a lot of learning. If you just want a quick&dirty hack, you could just print everything out once, record the node names that ET gives you, and search accordingly—e.g., use `"{http://opendatakit.org/submissions}image_close"` instead of `"image_close"`, or use `et.find("{http://opendatakit.org/submissions}"+element_name)`. It's definitely hacky, but if it gets you through today's problem today, it may be worth considering.